# Lookup on 2 datasets in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am having a problem using Lookups in a ssrs report. The report takes in 3 datasets that I do not have the opportunity to edit or merge (three different cubes)

It is a sales report that should be grouped by Sales Manager and show the potential for sales and a "discounted potential" of sales. The problem I face is that I have to loop my table on DataSet1 since it is the only on that holds Sales Mangers.

Using LookupSet and LookupSum it is easy enough to get the potential from DataSet2. Something like:

=Code.LookupSum(LookupSet(Fields!Country.Value, Fields!Country.Value, Fields!Potential.Value, "DataSet2"))

The problem arises when I try to calculate the Discounted Potential form DataSet3

Namely because I need to perform the lookup based on a value that is not in DataSet1! Is this somehow possible?

The datasets and the desired report look like this

Comment: There should have been an image there, let me figure out how to include it

Comment: The image isn't showing so here is a direct link to it https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1N4h.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to change the dataset of the tablix to `DataSet2` to get the desired results. `Dataset2` is the only dataset that directly relates to both of the other datasets, and since nested `Lookups` are not allowed, and also since you cannot modify your datasets, this is necessary for this situation.

I'm not sure exactly what calculation you are using to end up with your "Discount" column, I couldn't figure out any formula that worked with all of your sample data shown. For my test I just took the Sum to make sure it was working, but you should be able to modify that to fit your needs.

I set up a tablix like so:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| Manager |  Country  |    Potential     | Discount |
| <Expr1> | [Country] | [Sum(Potential)] | <Expr2>  |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

With 2 row groups, the first grouping on Expr1, and the child group grouping on Country, where Expr1 is `=Lookup(Fields!Country.Value, Fields!Country.Value, Fields!Manager.Value, "DataSet1")` and Expr2 is `=Sum(Code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!Customer.Value, Fields!Customer.Value, Fields!Discount.Value, "DataSet3")))`. I sorted the parent row group by Country to keep the sorting the same as you had it in your screenshot. Again though, you would likely have to modify Expr2 to fit your needs. If the discount is a percentage for that particular customer, then the following code should work for that, but the results don't match your screenshot so I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
=Sum(Fields!Potential.Value - (Fields!Potential.Value * Code.SumLookup(LookupSet(Fields!Customer.Value, Fields!Customer.Value, Fields!Discount.Value, "DataSet3")) / 100))
```

[image]

[image]

Results from using the modified Expr2 if Discount is a percentage:

[image]